# Do we have to assume a parser is pre-reading tokens ahead of time?

Tags: parsing, token, lexer, lemon

Coming back to lexers and parsers after many years away, I find myself puzzled over the concept of a state change, for the purposes of context. I'm using Lemon as a parser and putting together my own lexer.

Let's take an example input like this one:

```
[groups]
syscon:
    0x000   sysmemremap
    0x004   presetctrl

[registers]
sysmemremap:
    map     1-0
    rsvd    31-2
presetctrl:32
    mux     2-0
..etc...
```

So "syscon:" and "sysmemremap:" look the same but one is a GROUPNAME and the other is a REGISTERNAME. There's a context change between [groups] and [registers] that determines what each token is in reality.

Is it the parser that is in the best position to make that contexual change? As the parser doesn't have a sectional grammar, where one set of grammar applies in one set of circumstances and another in a different set, I presume the lexer should be the one deciding that "syscon:" generates a GROUPNAME if the mode is such that it should.

EDIT: Just spotted "the lexer hack" entry in Wikipedia that summarises the issue:

> Without added context, the lexer cannot distinguish type identifiers
>   from other identifiers because all identifiers have the same format.
>   .... The solution generally consists of feeding information from the
>   semantic symbol table back into the lexer. That is, rather than
>   functioning as a pure one-way pipeline from the lexer to the parser,
>   there is a backchannel from semantic analysis back to the lexer.

Except (and this is the question I have) what can you assume about the parser's pre-reading of tokens? If the parser is bashing ahead and reading more tokens to do a better match - which I would expect it to do to some extent at least, it could well run into the situation that a state change in the parser is too late for the lexer as it already met and processed that token!

Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

I may be able to answer my own question. I think that any sort of reliance on what the parser is doing internally is likely a Bad Plan.

Now that I've found my Lex and Yacc book (the O'Reilly one), one of the examples in the Lex section is a state change one - If it see the word "verb" it starts defining verbs as opposed to looking them up. That work is done in the lexer so I guess that's the way it is - do it in the lexer.